# How to register service workers to a redirected script URL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, service-worker

This might fall under the category of "don't do that", but I'm attempting to develop a chrome extension that effectively injects a web-accessible service worker script ("sw.js") into a user's page, and then registers a service worker to that script.

Right now, I have the following:
Manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "MyApp",
  "description": "none",
  "version": "1.0",
  "incognito": "split",
  "web_accessible_resources": ["sw.js"],
  "permissions": [

          "webRequestBlocking","webRequest",
          "*://*/*"
        ],

  "background": 
  {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["initPage.js"],
      "all_frames": false
    }]
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(details) {
    return {redirectUrl: chrome.extension.getURL("sw.js")};
  },
  {urls: ["*://*/switchme.js"]},
  ["blocking"]);
```

initPage.js:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/switchme.js').then(function(registration) {
      console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ',    registration.scope);
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
  })
}
```

Hopefully from this, you'll see what I'm *trying* to accomplish. Basically, I want to attempt to register a service worker to `sw.js`, which is hosted in the web-accessible-scripts in the extension. The way I believe I can do this is by intercepting the request for `switchme.js` and redirecting it to return `sw.js`.

The only problem with this approach is that my chrome browser crashes when I attempt this. I traced the stack into the line of `extensions::sendRequest`:

```
nativeFunction(functionName,
  request.args,
  requestId,
  hasCallback,
  optArgs.forIOThread,
  optArgs.preserveNullInObjects);
```

Any debugging ideas or slaps upside the head with a nice explanation of why I'm crazy to think this might work are appreciated.

Comment: The browser crashes at which line? Have you checked to use a specific url instead of `"*://*/switchme.js"`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried a specific URL. I can't pinpoint the exact location the browser crashes since it happens in the "nativeFunction" call, which I don't have visibility into.

Comment: I am 99% sure that this falls under the category of "don't do that". But it would be a good idea if you could visit `chrome://crashes/` after triggering a crash and filing a bug with the information from there. What you're attempting should ideally fail with a meaningful error message instead of crashing.

Answer (score 0):

The browser crashing seems to be related to [this reported bug on the chromium issue tracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=545531).

However, note that [this change in the chromium source](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/3868550081d275ef8f73933ffcec88da453215a2), suggests the problem is no longer in registering service workers from an extension's URL.

From the commit message:

> [Service Worker Registration] Registered extension scheme to allow
>   service workers
>
> Service Workers require a secure origin, such as HTTPS. 
>   chrome-extension:// pages are not HTTP/HTTPS, but are secure so this
>   change becomes a necessary step to allow extensions to register a
>   Service Worker.
>
> "chrome-extension" is added as a scheme allowing service workers.

---

As a footnote, service workers in chrome extensions are still a work-in-progress. You can follow its progress by tracking [this issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=545535).